# Why implementation gradle dependecies are exposed to consumers

Tags: gradle

The [java-library plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) says:

> Dependencies appearing in the api configurations will be transitively exposed to consumers of the library, and as such will appear on the compile classpath of consumers. 
>   Dependencies found in the implementation configuration will, on the other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into the consumers' compile classpath

However, it doesn't work for me. I see that the implementation dependencies are exposed to consumers too.
Here one example:

**project_a -> build.gradle**

```
...
dependencies {
  // Dependency supposedly not exposed to consumers in their own classpath compilation  
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
}
...
```

**project_b -> build.gradle**

```
...
dependencies {      
  implementation 'my-company:project_a:1.0'
}
...
```

I expected that guava doesn't appear in the project_b' classpath. However I see guava and all their dependencies on the project_b compile classpath.

**project_b>> gradlew dependencies:**

```
...
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- my-company:project_a:1.0
     \--- com.google.guava:guava:23.0
          +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
          +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.18
          +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
          \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14
...
```

Comment: Can you indicate the version of Gradle you use and how `project_b` consumes `project_a`? Is it through a maven repository? a composite build? other?

Comment: Yes, gradle version is 4.8. project_b consumes project_a from local maven repository. I see guava as runtime dependency in the project_a.pom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you do not experience this behaviour is because your dependency goes through a Maven POM.

The separation of the Maven `compile` and `runtime` scopes is only [supported as of Gradle 4.6](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#compile/runtime-scope-separation-in-pom-consumption) and is currently behind a feature flag.

In short, if you add the following to `settings.gradle` of `project_b`, you will get the expected behaviour:

```
enableFeaturePreview("IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT")
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the documentation refers to multi-project builds, and that a *consumer* is considered to be a project (not a jar) that depends on another project in the build.

For example, consider this `project_b/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':project_a')
}
```

With this (and the appropriate `settings.gradle`), I can observe the compile classpath changes as the doc describes (for use of `api` versus `implementation`). I have placed a working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_50915722).

Comment: Thanks! your example works, but I don't find anything about that restriction in the documentation. I want to do a library for unknown consumers, so the implementation dependency seemed to be a great option to avoid exposing my dependencies. Someone knows some way to achieve that? Thanks.